# Futur II Passive Subjunctive, "werden"

Tags: grammar-style

This is not a real world example of something someone will say, but we (two native speakers) were discussing whether the following sentence is grammatically correct:

"Würden in zehn Jahren mehr Menschen Handwerker geworden worden sein, werden viele Probleme von heute obsolet geworden worden sein."

Is this correct German and if not, what would be the correct phrase?

I tried to do some Internet research, but this borderlines on somewhere between grammar and art and I have to admit I wasn't able to apply the rules I found to this combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich erlaube mir mal eine Antwort auf deutsch, weil die Frage für Leute, die sich mit Deutsch noch gar nicht wohlfühlen, wahrscheinlich auch weniger interessant ist.

Was möchtet Ihr denn mit diesem "geworden worden sein" ausdrücken? Was ist  "geworden werden"? Für mich ergibt das keinen Sinn. Man kann etwas geworden sein, man kann auch zu etwas ausgebildet worden sein, aber man kann nicht etwas geworden worden sein.

Zudem benutzt ihr im ersten Teil des Satzes einen Irrealis (würden), das heißt, dieser Teil geht davon aus, dass es nicht so kommen wird. Der zweite Teil benutzt aber "werden", und das bedeutet, dass man denkt, dass es so kommt.

Der korrekte Satz im Futur II lautet (wenn man glaubt, dass es so kommt, sonst mit 2x "würden" statt "werden"):

> "Werden in zehn Jahren mehr Menschen Handwerker geworden sein, werden viele Probleme von heute obsolet geworden sein."

Mit einem anderen Verb, bei dem auch das Passiv einen Sinn ergibt, ist eure kompliziertere Konstruktion aber auch richtig, zum Beispiel:

> "Werden in zehn Jahren mehr Menschen zu Handwerkern ausgebildet worden sein, werden damit viele Probleme von heute obsolet gemacht worden sein."

Comment: Danke, für mich hätte "geworden worden" sein immer ausdrücken sollen, dass das Werden in der Zukunft beginnt, eine Zeit andauert, aber auch schon zu dem Zeitpunkt aufgehört hat, über den ich gerade spreche. Wahrscheinlich war ich da einfach komplett auf dem Holzweg. Danke für Deine Zeit.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it should be:
Wenn in zehn Jahren mehr Menschen zu Handwerkern ausgebildet sein werden, werden damit viele Probleme von heute nicht mehr bestehen.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).